# commands to install python 2.7 on linuxbox

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having python 2.6 on my linux box,i need to update it to python 2.7..can anyone provide steps on how to do this?

```
sudo pip install .....
```

Comment: You need to upgrade it with your distribution's package manager.

Comment: @Blender - how to do this?i have sudo permissions on the box

Comment: What linux distribution are you using.  It is *impossible* to give you instructions if we don't know this information because each linux distribution uses a different package manager.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link if the OS is Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-python-2-7-2-on-ubuntu.

Else try this: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/python2.html

It's pretty self explainatory.